# HTML Minification: Whitespace between element attributes

Tags: html, cross-browser, whitespace, minify, specifications

I'd like to remove more *unnecessary* bytes from my output, and it seems it's *acceptable* (in practice) to strip what can add up to quite a lot of whitespace from HTML markup by omitting/collapsing the gaps between DOM element attributes.

Although I've tested and researched (a little in both cases), I'm wondering how *safe* it would be?

I tested in **Chrome** `(43.0.2357.65 m)`, **IE** `(11.0.9600.17801)`, **FF** `(38.0.1)` and **Safari** `(5.1.7 (blah-di-blah))` and they didn't seem to mind, and couldn't find anything specific in [The Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) about whitespace between attributes.

[w3.org's Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) complains, which is a strong indication that this is not *safe* and shouldn't be expected to work, but (there's always a "but") it's possible the *requirement* for a space is only strict when no quotes are present (for obvious reasons).
<sup>Also (snippy but poignant): their SSL is *"out of date"* which doesn't inspire confidence in their *opinion*.</sup>

I noted also that [someone's HTML *compressor*](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) could (when enabled) strip quotes around attribute values where those values had no whitespace within them (*e.g.* `id`), which implies that at least most if not all HTML parsing is focussed on the text either side of the equals signs (except with booleans of course), and where quotes are in use, they'd be considered the prioritized delimiter.

So, would:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<a href="http://example.org"target="_blank"title="This is a test">Yabba Dabba Doo!</a>
</body></html>
```

▲ that ever go wrong, and if so, under which conditions?

What other reasons could there be to maintain this whitespace in production output (code *"readability"* is a non issue in this case)?

## Update (since finding *an* answer):

Although I basically answered my own question insofar that there is a specification governing whether there *should be* a space between attributes, I still wonder if omitting them when using quoted values can be considered practically *safe*, and would appreciate feedback on this point.

Considering how often spaces may be omitted by accident in production HTML, and that the browsers I tested don't seem to mind when they are, I assume it would be very rare if ever that a browser failed to handle documents with these spaces omitted.

Although it's sensible to follow the specs in pretty much all situations, might this be one time *cheating a bit* could be *acceptable*?

After all - if we can *magically* save several hundred bytes without affecting the quality of the output, why not?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but what do the relevant html specs say? If the spec says it's valid, then it's valid, otherwise the permissive nature of browsers should not be relied upon (and such permissiveness is, in my mind, a perpetuated mistake from the first generation of browsers, though one that arguably helped the web in its early days).

Comment: @DavidThomas : As stated, I haven't found anything in the specs I've read that even mentions the spaces - let alone whether they're required. That's why I'm asking the question. Hopefully someone actually knows, or knows that there is no specification for/about them - in which case permission can be assumed as granted by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is a specification (after all)

It turns out I should have looked harder. My bad.

According to [these specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#attributes-2):

> If an attribute using the empty attribute syntax is to be followed by another attribute, then **there must be a space character separating the two**.

and

> If an attribute using the unquoted attribute syntax is to be followed by another attribute or by the optional U+002F SOLIDUS character (/) allowed in step 6 of the start tag syntax above, then **there must be a space character separating the two**.

and

> If an attribute using the single-quoted attribute syntax is to be followed by another attribute, then **there must be a space character separating the two**.

and

> If an attribute using the double-quoted attribute syntax is to be followed by another attribute, then **there must be a space character separating the two**.

Which unless I am mistaken (again), means there must **always** be spaces between attributes.

Comment: Good find! I half remembered mention of white-space in the specs, but, on mobile, I wasn't able to find them. And yes, mandatory white-space is how I read those statements too. Still, have you considered sending your html and CSS gzipped to reduce bandwidth?

Comment: @DavidThomas : Oh, everything possible is already squished. I'm just never satisfied, and always look for moar. The inspiration was practically doubling a site's HTML markup (by byte) by fleshing out with schema.org markup. There's already the usual `class`s, `id`s and so on, and some `data-*`s - then yet more attributes! I just noticed the potential saving and tests made it look feasible. But nope - not safely anyway. Thanks for giving it some thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try online HTML minifiers like http://www.whak.ca/minify/HTML.htm or http://www.scriptcompress.com/minify-HTML.htm (search google for more) and find little things they change for hints to what can be taken out yet still render the HTML code.

On the first link your code:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<a href="http://example.org"target="_blank"title="This is a test">Yabba Dabba Doo!</a>
</body></html>`

Turns into:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=http://example.org target=_blank title="This is a test">Yabba Dabba Doo!</a>`

saving you 18 bytes already...

Comment: Your browser may ignore the extra whitespace, but bandwidth does mind and data transfers cost money to someone. So reducing transfer file sizes of HTML pages is saving someone money (web hosting companies, cell phone users on limited plans). Many 3rd world countries only have dial up, so smaller pages means faster loading...I have literally seen 200KB webpages where 20KB was useless whitespace and another 30KB for useless hidden comments...